# Loading and using an HLSL shader?

Tags: c++, directx, shaders, hlsl

I've been looking everywhere and all I can find are tutorials on writing the shaders. None of them showed me how to incorporate them into my scene.

So essentially:

Given an hlsl shader, if I were to have a function called drawTexturedQuad() and I wanted the shader to be applied to the result, how exactly could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: OpenGL dev here, but your method sound more like a FFP function that can't be combined with a shader. You have to draw the quad with texture yourself in the shader.

Comment: That's a funny question actually. And people making tutorials should be avare of this :). What version of DX are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three steps:

1. Load effect and set the technique
2. Provide data to the effect
3. Render

1) Load effect and set the technique

```
  // Declaration of your effect variable
  LPD3DXEFFECT  mDSEGeometryStage; 
  ...
  initEffects()
  {
  //With this method you load your effect file
  HR(**D3DXCreateEffectFromFile**( d3ddev, "./DeferredEffect_MaterialsStage.fx", 0, 0, D3DXSHADER_DEBUG, 0, &mDSEGeometryStage, &errors);) 
        // Some Error checking   
    if( errors )
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, (char *)errors->GetBufferPointer(), 0, 0);
        errors->Release();
    }       
    // Retrieve a Technique from your effects handler
    D3DXHANDLE mhTech = mDSEGeometryStage->**GetTechniqueByName**("MaterialsTech");
            // Set the technique to be used 
    HR(mDSEGeometryStage->SetTechnique(mhTech));
  }
```

2) Provide data to the effect:

```
renderGeometryStage()
{
    // Effect values handlers (String parameter is the name of a variable in your .fx file)
D3DXHANDLE mhView       = mDSEGeometryStage->GetParameterByName(0, "gView");            
D3DXHANDLE mhProjection = mDSEGeometryStage->GetParameterByName(0, "gProjection");      
D3DXHANDLE mhNearClip = mDSEGeometryStage->GetParameterByName(0, "gNearClip");
D3DXHANDLE mhFarClip = mDSEGeometryStage->GetParameterByName(0, "gFarClip");

    // Set effect values indicating the handler and the data as paramters
HR(mDSEGeometryStage->SetMatrix(mhProjection, &(camera->getProjectionMatrix())));
HR(mDSEGeometryStage->SetMatrix(mhView, &(camera->getViewMatrix())));       
HR(mDSEGeometryStage->SetFloat(mhFarClip, camera->getFarClip()));

    ...
```

3) Render: 
As said in a previous answer

> ID3DXEffect provides Begin() and
>   BeginPass() methods.

So, in the same rendering method you can start to render by calling the device BeginScene() method and inside call the Begin or BeginPass methods of your effect.

```
    ...

// Begin Scene  
HR(d3ddev->BeginScene());
{
                ...     

    // Clear targets surface
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET |D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, 
        D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0, 0,0,0), 1.0f, 0);    

    // Begin Effect passes.
    UINT numPasses = 0;
    HR(mDSEGeometryStage->Begin(&numPasses, 0))
    {
       // PLACE HERE YOUR RENDERING STUFF 
       // like:  drawTexturedQuad();    
    }
    // End Effect passes
    HR(mDSEGeometryStage->End());
}   
// End scene rendering
HR(d3ddev->EndScene());    
}// End of renderGeometryStage method
```

Hope it helps, but your question is not about a chunk of code that you can copy/paste, its more about "basic" concepts. So for this kind of things I really recommend you to follow some tutorial because you will understand all the underlying concepts better. Cheers!

Comment: Gotta upvote this- nice and comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

ID3DXEffect provides `Begin()` and `BeginPass()` methods. All you have to do is call DrawQuad() appropriately between them and their equivalent `End()` and `EndPass()` methods.

Answer (score -2):

Depends if you want to use OpenGL or Direct3D.

For D3D the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/aa937781) has all the gory details.

Comment: Hi welcome to Gamedev. Please read questions better. HLSL means directx, he also specified directx in tags.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot use HLSL with OpenGL. It is DirectX only.

Comment: Fair enough. But reading the DX SDK would give him the answer.